# ionic2 ios iframe video play inline

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I want to play iframe video as playinline. I have used following code

```
<iframe [src]="video" width="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen webkit-playsinline></iframe>
```

and I have added the preference to config xml file

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

Comment: and the problem is ? how is the `video` property set ?

Comment: if i play the video it will play  in full window of the mobile

Comment: you put the `webkit-playsinline` on an `iframe`, that should be on a `video` element.